# How can I run scheduler every one minute in Laravel without setting cron job?

Tags: laravel

I want to run the scheduler in every minute on the server without setting the cron job with ssh .Please let me know Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: you can use laravel scheduling feature for this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling check it here. let me know if you have any difficulty there

Comment: You'll have a hard time running scheduled tasks without setting up a cron job.

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: you have set cron job to your project directory

1. Create a command using

   `php artisan make:command CommandName`
2. add your logic under handle function

```
public function handle()
{
    //add your logic here
}
```

3. register your command under `Kernel.php` under `$commands` array

```
protected $commands = [
    Commands\Test::class,
];
```

4. schedule command under

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('command:name')->everyMinute();
}
```

Comment: This will do nothing without setting up a cron job to run the scheduler.

Comment: I already know this but I need such code that will add the cron path that is 
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
to the server

Comment: @MohitDevgn you can add it from SSH

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya Hi Thanks for replying
But I want there is any way that we don't need to add it manually ,need to add this programmatically not manually

Comment: @MohitDevgn you have to do this one time. not again and again

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya I know I have to do this one time but I don't want to add the cron path with the ssh manually ,want to do with the code ,I found no way for this if you have then please let me know.